# GCC:- unable to find libpthread_nonshared.a file while linking libraries to create a so file on Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pthreads, ld

Hi I'm trying to compile a c project with gcc 10.2 in Ubuntu 20.04.
But at the end it gives me error as below

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread_nonshared.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Below are the libraries I'm trying to link while creating a so file
`-lpthread -ldl -lm -lstdc++ -lrt`

When i looked into /usr/lib64 i could see only *.so files but no *.a files.

Do we need to install them separately?

Could someone help with this.

Answer (score 0):

> Do we need to install them separately?

You need to install `glibc-devel` (or similar) package.

Comment: I installed libc6-dev package ...Even then the library didn't exist